# Installing/Running Pyomo (command not found)

Tags: python, ubuntu, optimization, installation, pyomo

I installed Pyomo on my Ubuntu 15.10 according to the [install guide](https://software.sandia.gov/downloads/pub/pyomo/PyomoInstallGuide.html#InstallingPyomoUsers) using `pip install pyomo` which worked fine and returned `Successfully installed pyomo PyUtilib appdirs ply nose six`. (I installed pip and scientific python first.)

However, if I now test it with `pyomo --help`, I get `pyomo: command not found`.

Am I missing something? Do I somehow need to add pyomo to my path?

Am I not running it correctly? In the [quick start](https://software.sandia.gov/downloads/pub/pyomo/PyomoInstallGuide.html#_getting_started) it mentioned to import pyomo.core in python. I tried that but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Install guide has options. Which commands did you actually type into your terminal, exactly?

Comment: I did run exactly "pip install pyomo" or what command do you mean? I also added a screenshot of the output when running pip. Hope that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pip` is installing into your user-writeable `$HOME/.local` which is very likely just missing from you `$PATH` and `$PYTHONPATH` where linux looks for scripts to execute and python looks for modules to  import respectively.

Execute in a terminal session and try again:

```
export PATH=${HOME}/.local/bin:${PATH}
export PYTHONPATH=${HOME}/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:${PYTHONPATH}
```

If that helps, add those commands at the bottom of your `$HOME/.bashrc` so they get executed whenever you start a terminal session.

Comment: Thanks, I was suspecting it was something about the path but I couldn't find anything in the guide or online.
It works now.